# Filters for CBV ListView using GET from Previous and Current Page

Tags: python, django, listview

I am trying to add search functionality to a ListView in two places in my Django application. From the homepage, I want users to be able to filter by zip code, and on the ListView template, I also want users to have the ability to filter by another attribute in the model. My issue is that the self.request.GET.get('q') returns None when filtering from the ListView page, and I want it to retain the zip code filter that I used in the previous page.

For search functionality, I am using Q.

How can I retain the zip code filter from the initial request so that I can query on both zip code and category?

***views.py***

```
class ListingsView(ListView):
    
    model = Listing
    template_name = 'listings/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'listing_list'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_zip = self.request.GET.get('q_zip_code')
        query_category = self.request.GET.get('q_category')
        if query_category == None:
            queryset = Listing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip))
        else:
            queryset = Listing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip) & Q(category__icontains = query_category))
        return queryset
```

***home.html***

```
<p>
     <form class="form-homepage-search" action="{% url 'rental_listings_list' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q_zip_code" class="form-zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" aria-label="Zip Code">
          <button class="button" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
     </form>
</p>
```

***list.html***

```
<form class="form-listing-search" action="{% url 'rental_listings_list' %}" method="get">
     <input name="q_category" class="form-category" type="text" placeholder="Category" aria-label="Category">
     <button class="button" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Also open to other suggestions in the Q GET + filter method is not ideal for this use case. Perhaps Django-filters is better?

Answer (score 1):

Add in your `list.html`:

```
action="{% url 'rental_listings_list' %}?q_category={{ request.GET.q_category }}"
```

Comment: It works in the same way with this addition. On the list.html page, I have already filtered by q_zip_code, but I want the form to add q_category to the QuerySet so that I can filter by both zip code (retained from the home.html page) and the now added category. I tried it with <form class="form-listing-search" action="{% url 'rental_listings_list' %}?q_zip_code={{ request.GET.q_zip_code }}" method="get"> but did not get the anticipated outcome.

Comment: Been reading documentation and other posts for several hours now, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: can you print in view request.GET, and can you print in view Listing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip)) ?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'q_zip_code': ['1']}> for the first search, and <QueryDict: {'q_category': ['test']}> for the filter added. The issue is that I need to somehow retain the q_zip_code = 1 when I add the category filter on the page with the results of the first query.

Comment: I understand. I don't have a laptop now. You should add hidden input with zip code on the list html.

Comment: From view:
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_zip = self.request.GET.get('q_zip_code')
        query_category = self.request.GET.get('q_category')
        if query_category == None:
            queryset = RentalListing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip))
        else:
            query_zip = self.request.GET.get('q_zip_code')
            queryset = RentalListing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip) & Q(category__icontains = query_category))
        return queryset

Comment: From html:       <form class="form-listing-search" action="{% url 'rental_listings_list' %}?q_zip_code={{ request.GET.q_zip_code }}" method="get">
        <input name="request.GET.q_zip_code" type="hidden">
        <input name="q_category" class="form-category" type="text" placeholder="Category" aria-label="Category">
        <button class="button" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
      </form>

Comment: Still not passing the q_zip_code upon update.

Comment: Figured it out, see answer below. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out with help from Maxim!

Add to list.html

```
<input name="q_zip_code" type="hidden" value="{{ request.GET.q_zip_code }}">
```

Add to view.py

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_zip = self.request.GET.get('q_zip_code')
        query_category = self.request.GET.get('q_category')
        if query_category == None:
            queryset = RentalListing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip))
        else:
            query_zip = self.request.GET.get('q_zip_code', '')
            queryset = RentalListing.objects.filter(Q(zip_code__icontains = query_zip) & Q(category__icontains = query_category))
        return queryset
```